# How to change width of a UI Button by code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have installed unity 5.I can't understand how to change width of a button by c# code.also i need to change the font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using OnGui. You can use the Vector 3 or Rect.

But for 4.6 Unity new GUI UI. You will have to Manipulate the Anchor Points. Instead of the actual scaling.

The new GUI will always depend on its Parent, most commonly the Canvas as the Main Parent.

Make sure you use the namespace of
UnityEngine.UI;

or else you wont have the classes that you need to control it.

For buttons In the new UI, You will need extra work. Cause the Button class does not Inherit from the RectTransform Class which you will need to modify.

1st reference the Button that you will modify.

```
public Button myBtn;
//Drag the button in Unity3d in this script.
```

next we access its component RectTransform since it is applied to the gameObject but it is not inherited on Button class;

```
myBtn.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMax = new Vector2(30.0f, 30.0f);
myBtn.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMin = new Vector2(10.0f, 10.0f);
```

or just Reference the myBtn RectTransform component so you won't need to repeat the call.

In other Components however like Text, it is easier.

ex

```
Text myText;
// Drag the Text new GUI UI in the inspector.

myText.rectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(10.0f,10.0f);
// Because the Text class is a subclass of RectTransform or at lease there is a an object class rectTransform that is pointing to it.


// THIS is for the Font size.
myText.fontSize = 30;
```

Hope this helps you understand the new UI